# Comet performance issue

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf, comet, server-push

I'm studying about implementing Comet in my application.
I got that for each request there should be an open connection between client and server.
No suppose in my application I have 10 requests (push data from server to client), and I have just 10 users online, now I should have 100 (10*10) open connections between client and server.
Is it OK?
It doesn't have any performance issue?

Comment: You should have an open connection for each user, not each request.

Comment: but any user can have many requests, is it possible to wrap various requests in one channel?

Comment: Yes, that's what you do. Open a connection for a user and send all his requests through this connection.

Comment: Wouldn't websockets be more appropriate now?

Comment: Absolutely websockets is more appropriate but IE9 doesn't support it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Comet or with web sockets, you would have one connection open between each user and each server.  You can then send multiple requests across the one connection.

So, for 10 users, your server would have 10 connections (one for each user).